# javascript - DOM modification madness

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have this function, which I want to create a container div with two child divs, one being the title of the container and the other one being the content. For some reason, this is NOT working when I test it in jsfiddle.

**Also, I would like to know how to append this whole container to a div with a specific class in my html.**

```js
var add = function(title, content) {
  var addContainerBody = document.createElement("DIV");
  addContainerBody.className = "c-body";
  var addTitle = document.createElement("DIV");
  var titleText = document.createTextNode(title);
  addTitle.appendChild(titleText);
  addTitle.className = "title";
  var addContent = document.createElement("DIV");
  var contentText = document.createTextNode(content);
  addContent.className = "content";
  addContainerBody.appendChild(addTitle);
  addContainerBody.appendChild(addContent);
  document.body.appendChild(addContainerBody);
};

// Callin it //

add("Title","Text");
```

As you can see, it outputs only the title, and nothing else. I am probably missing something very obvious. What is the issue here?

Comment: Using the shadowDOM would be more effective here, ReactJS would be easiest if you want to abstract to a framework.

Comment: I don't know what that is and for this project I cannot use a seperate framework or plugin.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

Comment: Please try to make titles relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am probably missing something very obvious.

You're never appending the `contentText` to the `addContent` element.

```js
function add(title, content) {
  var addContainerBody = document.createElement("DIV");
  addContainerBody.className = "c-body";

  var addTitle = addContainerBody.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"));
  addTitle.className = "title";
  addTitle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));

  var addContent = addContainerBody.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"));
  addContent.className = "content";
  addContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));

  document.body.appendChild(addContainerBody);
}

add("Title","Text");
```

> I would like to know how to append this whole container to a div with a specific class in my html.

You can use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the div with that class, and then append to it instead of `document.body`. But make sure [that the element is already available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572) to be selected before executing your code.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my second question.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen: Uh, I didn't spot that. Better ask only one question per post :-)

Comment: I tried googling it and couldn't find an answer, and stackoverflow will only let you ask one question in a set interval.